# Add a foreign key when creating a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm trying to create a new table (Customer) and I'm trying to add the foreign key ZipCode, but its definitely not working I tried looking for possible solutions but I couldn't make it work with what I got. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE Zip_Code (
    ZipCode varchar(10) Not null,
    City varchar(20),
    StateCode varchar(2)
); 

ALTER TABLE Zip_Code
ADD Primary Key (ZipCode);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID INT Primary Key,
    CustomerName varchar(30),
    Address varchar(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (ZipCode) REFERENCES Zip_Code(ZipCode),
    CreditLimit money,
    Balance money,
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is not the primary key definition.  The problem is `customer`.  In order to declare a column as a foreign key, you have to define the column first:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID INT Primary Key,
    CustomerName varchar(30),
    Address varchar(30),
    ZipCode varchar(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (ZipCode) REFERENCES Zip_Code(ZipCode),
    CreditLimit money,
    Balance money,
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8f8083f8f4e152224c3c301032ffdb52) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

MY SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
        CustomerID int NOT NULL,
        ZipCode int,
        CustomerName varchar(30),
        Address varchar(30),
        PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID),
        FOREIGN KEY (ZipCode) REFERENCES Zip_Code(ZipCode)
    );
```

SQL Server / Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    CustomerID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerName varchar(30),
    Address varchar(30),
    ZipCode int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Zip_Code(ZipCode)
);
```